# Polars - drop duplicate row based on column subset but keep first

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

Given the following table, I'd like to remove the duplicates based on the column subset `col1,col2`. I'd like to keep the first row of the duplicates though:

```py
data = {
    'col1': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1],
    'col2': [7, 8, 9, 7, 7],
    'col3': [3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
}
tmp = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 7    ┆ 3    │
│ 2    ┆ 8    ┆ 4    │
│ 3    ┆ 9    ┆ 5    │
│ 1    ┆ 7    ┆ 6    │
│ 1    ┆ 7    ┆ 9    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

The result should be

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 7    ┆ 3    │
│ 2    ┆ 8    ┆ 4    │
│ 3    ┆ 9    ┆ 5    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Usually I'd do this with pandas `df["col1","col2"].is_duplicated(keep='first')`, but polars `dl.is_duplicated()` marks all rows as duplicates including the first occurence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.unique`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unique.html); the flexible `keep` keyword argument is here in Polars.

```py
tmp.unique(('col1', 'col2'), keep='first', maintain_order=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It could also be expressed in terms of a [`.filter()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html#polars.DataFrame.filter)

- [`pl.struct()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.struct.html#polars.struct) can be used to combine multiple columns/expressions as a single "key"
- [`is_first_distinct()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_first_distinct.html#polars.Expr.is_first_distinct) / [`is_last_distinct()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_last_distinct.html#polars.Expr.is_last_distinct) for first/last detection

```py
df.filter(pl.struct("col1", "col2").is_first_distinct())
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 7    ┆ 3    │
│ 2    ┆ 8    ┆ 4    │
│ 3    ┆ 9    ┆ 5    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```